# In "FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()" only getInstance part showing unresolved symbol?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
package com.example.vivanksharma.firebase;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText valueField;
    Button button;
    DatabaseReference rootRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        button = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        valueField = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        rootRef = new FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://url_of_my_database");

    }
}
```

> FirebaseDatabase.***getInstance()***.getReferenceFromUrl("https://url_of_my_database");

In this part of code `getInstance` is showing "Cannot resolve symbol error"
Any suggestions why ? 
I am using latest version of AndroidStudio also I have connected my app to database using Tools>Firebase assistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the **new** keyword. This FirebaseDatabase uses a Singleton instance, so simply:

```
 rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://url_of_my_database");
```